# 500px and Adobe Stock pay just with PayPal or had another option?

Tags: digital, selling, adobe, 500px

What other options do I have with these platforms? I currently live in Paraguay which doesn't allow me to receive payments through PayPal.

Comment: Hi Dario and welcome to Photo.SE. You can better ask these kind of questions at the customer service of these services, rather than the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to 500px.com's [payout support article](https://support.500px.com/hc/en-us/articles/204546358-How-do-I-get-paid-and-track-my-sales-), it appears the only digital payment service they currently support is PayPal:

> We can send payments via the following (please note that options vary by country):
>
> - eCheck / Local Bank Transfer: $5 fee
> - ACH: Free
> - Wire Transfer: $15-$26 fee
> - PayPal: Free*
>
>   * We do not charge for PayPal transfers, however they may be subject to PayPal fees.

Adobe Stock [supports the following payout methods](https://helpx.adobe.com/stock/contributor/help/getting-paid.html):

> Requesting a payment
>
> You can request a payout via PayPal, Payoneer, or Skrill when you have accrued $50 or more in royalties. Before you can submit your first payment request, the following criteria must be met: [...]
>
> - You must have a valid PayPal, Payoneer, or Skrill account to receive funds. You can set up your chosen account as part of the payment request process. Payoneer is initially only available for contributors outside of the United States who receive payments in USD currency, which includes contributors from South America, Australia, Russia, and Ukraine. See Payoneer FAQ for information on how to set up your account. We look forward to expanding the availability of the Payoneer feature to the rest of the world in the near future.

It looks like Payoneer will work for you. (I don't know for sure though)

Comment: Thanks for That, as you said Payoneer it's my only options on Adobe Stock, sadly 500px don't support it.